# I want to make Drop left rather then drop down

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make Drop left rather then drop down in bootstrap drop down button. I'm trying to make this happen but i can't able to do this, Can anyone guide me to do this?

Here is my code

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
<div class="btn-group">
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Small button <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu ">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Action 1</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger">Action 2</button>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})
</script>
```

Comment: Do you mean menu should be appear in left rather then bottom?

Comment: What have you tried? What you've shown just looks like generic Bootstrap dropdown markup with nothing extra.

Comment: @Leothelion u r right

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I tried on inspect element and some test code but my test code doesn't work so i can not place here.

Comment: .dropdown-menu{top:-10%;left:99%;} use this in your css with !important but keep in mind its work arround. Check other effect or use this css with custom class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of the css where there is `top` and `left`:

```
.dropdown-menu {
  top: -10px !important;
  left: -160% !important;
}
```

Comment: You have forget to add !important and second one simply should not change the base classes of bootstrap as it will effect on whole site so better use with custom class.

Comment: Yup that's the right way to do work without affecting basic classes of bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

try adding this

```
.dropdown-menu {
  left:auto;
  right:100%;
  top:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use css to achieve this.
I am currently on mobile but i believe it would go something like this. Try:

```
.dropdown-menu {
    margin-left:30px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

I should be something like this. You will now be able to show the opening  on to your left.